# Error when trying streaming video with opencv python

Tags: python, flask

Error when trying streaming video with opencv

```
def gen_frame():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://iotctu.ddns.net:8080/cgi-bin/jpeg?connect=start&framerate=10&resolution=640&quality=1&UID=23174&Language=0")

while (True):
    frame = cap.read()
    convert = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + convert + b'\r\n')
```

The error is

```
@app.route('/video_feed') def video_feed(): return Response(gen_frame(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame') TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Comment: Please explain the answer you gave so it is easy to follow what you did and why you did it.

Comment: Do briefly add your target what you're trying to achieve.